# How do large servers process multiple Requests

Tags: multithreading, sockets, winsock2

I am working on a project where I have to develop a server which supports file transfer through HTTP in windows. I have a thread running for receiving data, transmitting data, and another to process my data.

Basically, when the receive thread receives data from the network it posts to the processing thread.

When I started testing with file transfer, I noticed that if 2 clients try to send files simultaneously, my `recv`() function first returns the data of the client which was connected first, and then only will give me the data of the second client. With file transfer, as the files can be huge, the data taken for the 2nd client to be processed will be extremely long.

Is there a way where I can receive parallely?

I am sure actual servers do it.

Comment: this link may help :http://www.coderanch.com/t/563089/sockets/java/webserver-handle-multiple-requests-single

Comment: You need to create a thread per connection.